# Axios.post array from Vue js to Laravel, only get [object Object] in my request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue js, I have tried to find answers for my problem everywhere but in vain.
I just try to send an array (shopping cart) to Laravel from Vue component, but I only get [object Object] when I try to use foreach loop to get the items in the array. What do I do wrong?
I should be able to get name of title, quantity and price etc., this all works in my website in Vue component, but when I try to send to Laravel it is impossible to read it.

This is **some** of my code, please advice me.

```
<form action="../api/checkout" method="post" @submit="checkout">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Artiklar</th>
                <th scope="col">Antal</th>
                <th scope="col">Pris</th>
                <th scope="col">Summa</th>
                <th scope="col">Radera</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <input type="hidden" name="cartobj" v-bind="cartitem">
            <tr v-for="(crt, index) in cart" :key="index">
                
            <td>{{ crt.title }}<br><img :src="/image/+crt.image" :alt="crt.image" style="height: 80px;"></td>
            <td>{{ crt.qty }} st <br><div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-link col-md-6" @click="decrease(index)">-</button> 
                <button class="btn btn-link col-md-6" @click="increase(index)">+</button>
                </div></td>
            <td>{{ crt.subprice }} kr</td>
            <td>{{ (crt.subprice*crt.qty).toFixed(2) }} kr</td>
            <td><button @click="removecart(index)" class="btn btn-link"><img src="/pic/trash.png" alt="" width="20"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 

<p class="border rounded text-right p-2"><b>Total: {{ subsum }} kr</b></p>

<button id="checkout" class="btn btn-success col">Gå till kassan</button>
 </form>


export default {
    props: ['product'],
    data() {
        return {
            cartitem: {
                title: this.product.article,
                qty: 1,
                subprice: (this.product.price/100).toFixed(2),
                image: this.product.image
            },
            cart: []
        }
    },checkout() {
            let c = {cartobj: this.cart}; 
            axios.post('../api/checkout', JSON.stringify(c));
        }
```

From my controller, I have tried many different things, but can not get it to work, even nestled foreach loops...

```
public function checkout(Request $request) 
    {
        $cart = request();
        foreach($cart as $d=>$c) {
            echo $d;
        }
        die();
        
    }
```

Comment: To see exactly what your Vue application is sending to the server, you can use the Network Tools in your browser's development console. Here is an example of how to do that for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into this and come back.

Comment: It looks like the array is okay, but I think the problems are on the server side now...

Comment: You might have luck with `$cart = $request->input('cartobj');` to grab the `cartobj: this.cart` information sent from the `checkout` function

Comment: I will try this solution too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code to this and see if that helps:

```
    public function checkout(Request $request) 
    {
        $cart = $request->all();
        foreach($cart as $d=>$c) {
           echo $d;
        }
        die();
    
    }
```

You can also access specific input values, like this:

```
    $name = $request->input('name');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried this but it is not working either...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML form contains inputs with object values:

`<input type="hidden" name="cartobj" v-bind="cartitem">`

Submitting a native form with an input like this will result in `[object Object]` being sent in the request.

And, although configured to call the `checkout` function upon submit, the form is also configured to POST to `../api/checkout` without the use of JavaScript:

`<form action="../api/checkout" method="post" @submit="checkout">`

What is likely happening here:

- User submits form

  - `checkout()` is called
  - In parallel, the native form is submitted. The native form takes priority

You can prevent the native form from submitting itself by using `@submit.prevent="checkout"`, like this:

`<form @submit.prevent="checkout">`

Adding `.prevent` to a Vue event handler stops the native handlers from firing. In this case, `.prevent` stops the HTML form from being submitted without the use of the `checkout` function.

For more information on Vue's `.prevent`, see the [Vue Event Modifier docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

For more information on preventing the native handling of events, see [Event.preventDefault() on MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, is there another way to do it?
Can I skip input and send the array directly?

Comment: The hidden input could be removed here yep - they are generally most useful for including data in native forms. Axios will send the data given to it in the `checkout` function